# Using Magento Header and Footer with vBulletin

Tags: css

I have a Magento website currently in development and would like to have vBulletin 4 forums setup for my customers.

Is it possible to use the Magento Header/Navigation and Footer with vBulletin forums?  Would it be possible to "wrap" vBulletin inside of the Magento navigation of my main site?

Answer (score 1):

At my work we use a custom blend of Magento and a CMS where the navigation/footer is configured in Magento's admin section, and then passed to the CMS via Magento's SOAP API. The CMS we use is Zend-based, so it makes things easier.

Unfortunately, I don't know the specifics of how to accomplish this.

I hope this provides you with some hope?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the very least it proves that it is possible.

Comment: You're welcome. I apologize for not being able to offer more details at the moment. I will attempt to gather some more information and provide you with what I find.